# Elasticsearch ~2.0 php - cannot establish connection -array to string conversion error

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Following the elasticsearch documentation I installed the current php library ie 2.0 and I did this

```
$hosts = [
  // This is effectively equal to: "https://username:password!#$?*abc@foo.com:9200/"
  [
    'host' => 'foo.com',
    'port' => '9200',
    'scheme' => 'https',
    'user' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password!#$?*abc'
  ],

  // This is equal to "http://localhost:9200/"
  [
    'host' => 'localhost',    // Only host is required
  ]
];

$client = ClientBuilder::create()  // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
              ->setHosts($hosts)   // Set the hosts
              ->build();
```

But it is throwing array to string conversion error from the **buildConnectionsFromHosts** method. I am unable to establish connection.

I inspected the code and found that there is no code to process host given in array form.Is this the bug in the library or I am missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: This is the configuration example from the documentation provided in the elasticsearch website. Please have a look at this .https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html

Comment: If you were actually following the guide, it looks to me you are opening an https connection when you don't have one enabled for your host.

If this **is** the actual configuration you are using locally, then it won't work, no matter what, since you won't be able to connect to an elasticsearch on foo.com

Comment: @Bjorn I am aware of that fact and this is sample configuration I copied as I cannot show my actual configuration here. At least this should not throw array to string conversion error because of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution**

The "password" key in the host options should be replaced with "pass".

The **ClientBuilder.php** file in the library needs to be modified. The below code is not there in elasticsearch-php 2.0 ClientBuilder.php file but is in its master branch.

I replaced **buildConnectionsFromHosts** method

```
/**
         * @param array $hosts
         *
         * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
         * @return \Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection[]
         */
        private function buildConnectionsFromHosts($hosts)
        {
            if (is_array($hosts) === false) {
                $this->logger->error("Hosts parameter must be an array of strings, or an array of Connection hashes.");
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Hosts parameter must be an array of strings, or an array of Connection hashes.');
            }

            $connections = [];
            foreach ($hosts as $host) {
                if (is_string($host)) {
                    $host = $this->prependMissingScheme($host);
                    $host = $this->extractURIParts($host);
                } else if (is_array($host)) {
                    $host = $this->normalizeExtendedHost($host);
                } else {
                    $this->logger->error("Could not parse host: ".print_r($host, true));
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse host: ".print_r($host, true));
                }
                $connections[] = $this->connectionFactory->create($host);
            }

            return $connections;
        }
```

and added **normalizeExtendedHost** method

```
 /**
     * @param $host
     * @return array
     */
    private function normalizeExtendedHost($host) {
        if (isset($host['host']) === false) {
            $this->logger->error("Required 'host' was not defined in extended format: ".print_r($host, true));
            throw new RuntimeException("Required 'host' was not defined in extended format: ".print_r($host, true));
        }

        if (isset($host['scheme']) === false) {
            $host['scheme'] = 'http';
        }
        if (isset($host['port']) === false) {
            $host['port'] = '9200';
        }
        return $host;
    }
```